# Delphi FMX TListview - display a default png if table Blob is null

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

Instead of storing a default.png into every row of the database where the image is empty (waste of database space), is there a way to display this default.png in the Listview wherever image is empty/null in the table?

(I'm using livebindings by code).

Answer (score 1):

You can check and set in ListView UpdateObjects Event:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  if not Assigned(AItem.Bitmap) then
    AItem.Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
end;
```

best regards 
Moskw@

Comment: I tried it.  It doesn't work... in the debugger, the code runs through the line, but the graphic is not displayed.

Comment: Are you sure that assigned bitmap is not empty ?

Comment: I checked the database - it says the field is null. so it's strange.  anyway, the AItem.bitmap seems to be assigned at run-time. I modified to check for size of bitmap and it can work. Thanks!